# Parse Object id issue

Tags: parse-platform, objectid

```
ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("GameData");
parseObject.setObjectId("id-111"); // it won't work
```

so i created my own id:

```
parseObject.add("id","id-111");
```

But when every i try to update data for same id then it create different different entry for it. 
One solution it that i can fetch ParseObject for that id and then update that fetched object.
But it will take 2 network operation.

#### Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: you don't need to set objectId in advance, parse will do it for you in correct format which is like "MBcQomMdzU" , you just set ids of objects if you know them in advance, for new objects let the platform do the work

Comment: @PetrV post your answer as an Answer so it can be up-voted and marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set objectId in advance, parse will do it for you in correct format which is like "MBcQomMdzU" , you just set ids of objects if you know them in advance, for new objects let the platform do the work.

If you set the objectId in advance you are creating reference to existing object with empty datafields, which you may work with, but you would still need to tell it to fetch the data fields, methods like fetch, fetchIfneeded, fetchInBackgroundWithBlock are available...

Answer (score 0):

@PetrV is absolutely correct and we should not create objectId's ourselves.

```
One solution is that i can fetch ParseObject for that id and then update that fetched object.
```

This approach of yours is correct and I feel the only way to ensure you are updating the correct ParseObject.

Another possible way is to fetch **objectId** created by Parse itself by calling `yourObject.getObjectId()` and then updating the object matching this id. However this will also involve two network calls.

The only thing above will save you from is creating an extra column i.e. id as you have done in your code. :)